# Read Json Value from a SQL Server table

Tags: json, t-sql, json-query, json-value

I have a Json value stored in SQL server table as ntext:

JSON (column: json_val):

```
[{"prime":{"image":{"id":"123","logo":"","productId":"4000","enable":true},"accountid":"78","productId":"16","parentProductId":"","aprx":"4.599"}}]
```

```
select JSON_VALUE(cast(json_val as varchar(8000)), '$.prime.aprx') as px
from table_1
where id = 1
```

Whenever I execute it, i receive a null. What's wrong with the query?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why `cast(json_val as varchar(8000))` ? Isn't that field a text field already? As for the JSON path, this JSON string is an *array* with a single element.

Comment: Why are you storing such regular data in a JSON field though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON string is an array with a single item. You need to specify the array index to retrieve a specific item, eg :

```
declare @t table (json_val  nvarchar(4000))

insert into @t
values ('[{"prime":{"image":{"id":"123","logo":"","productId":"4000","enable":true},"accountid":"78","productId":"16","parentProductId":"","aprx":"4.599"}}]')

select JSON_VALUE(cast(json_val as varchar(8000)), '$[0].prime.aprx') as px
from @t
```

This returns `4.599`

If you want to search all array entries, you'll have to use OPENJSON. If you need to do that though ...

**Avoid JSON if possible**

JSON storage is *not* an alternative to using a proper table design though. JSON fields can't be indexed, so filtering by a specific field will always result in a full table scan. Given how regular this JSON string is, you should consider using proper tables instead

Answer (score 1):

As Panagiotis said in the comments:

> As for the JSON path, this JSON string is an array with a single element

Instead, therefore, you can use `OPENJSON` which would inspect each array:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'[{"prime":{"image":{"id":"123","logo":"","productId":"4000","enable":true},"accountid":"78","productId":"16","parentProductId":"","aprx":"4.599"}}]';

SELECT aprx
FROM (VALUES(@JSON))V(json_val)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.json_val)
                 WITH (aprx decimal(4,3) '$.prime.aprx');
```

As also mentioned, your JSON should already be a string data type (should be/probably an `nvarchar(MAX)`) so there's no reason to `CAST` it.